# Use max of column and if null use min

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 10 milestones in the column `milestone`. The column `milestone_achieved` has either the value `OK` or `NULL`.
The `name` column has just names, whenever someone new enters, all the milestones are entered in the database with `NULL`.

Here is what a typical table looks like:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------+
| name | milestone | milestone_achieved |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
| John |         1 | OK                 |
| John |         2 | OK                 |
| John |         3 | NULL               |
| John |         4 | NULL               |
| John |         5 | NULL               |
| John |         6 | NULL               |
| Mary |         1 | OK                 |
| Mary |         2 | OK                 |
| Mary |         3 | OK                 |
| Mary |         4 | OK                 |
| Mary |         5 | OK                 |
| Mary |         6 | OK                 |
| Tim  |         1 | NULL               |
| Tim  |         2 | NULL               |
| Tim  |         3 | NULL               |
| Tim  |         4 | NULL               |
| Tim  |         5 | NULL               |
| Tim  |         6 | NULL               |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Now I want the SQL query to return:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------+
| name | milestone | milestone_achieved |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
| John |         2 | OK                 |
| Mary |         6 | OK                 |
| Tim  |         1 | NULL               |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
```

My query right now looks like this:

```
SELECT name, MAX(milestone) FROM table HAVING milestone_achieved = 'OK' GROUP BY name
UNION ALL
SELECT name, MIN(milestone) FROM table HAVING milestone_achieved IS NULL AND MIN(milestone) = 1 GROUP BY name
```

This works in 90% of the cases, the problem occurs when e.g. milestone 1 and 2 was completed, but then milestone 1 was "uncompleted" because it didn't fit the specific criteria or whatever (imagine an assembly line where cars are assembled and a screw `=milestone 1` isn't tight enough but the paint `=milestone 2` is already on it or whatever else you can imagine, I have terrible imagination).

I am now looking fo a way to properly display those 10% cases.

Comment: What is the expected output for your outlier case?

Comment: I'm not sure your query does work.  The [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180199.aspx) clause can filter the results of [aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx) (SUM, MIN, MAX, etc).  It needs to be combined with the GROUP BY clause.  [WHERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188047.aspx) allows you to filter at the row level.  Nitpicking aside, your approach is on the right lines.  Gordon Linoff's answer below corrects these errors.

Comment: The output of the actual outlier case would be (if we assume Tim has revoked his `milestone 1` achievement: `John, 2, OK`, `Mary, 6, OK`, `Tim, 2, OK`, `Tim, 1, NULL`.

I actually want the `Tim, 1, NULL` to be gone from the result. The solution is in the answer by @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT name, MAX(milestone)
FROM table
WHERE milestone_achieved = 'OK'
GROUP BY name
UNION ALL
SELECT name, MIN(milestone)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(milestone_achieved) IS NULL;
```

This follows the structure of your logic.  You can do this with one `SELECT`:

```
SELECT name,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN milestone_achieved = 'OK' THEN milestone END),
                MIN(milestone)
               )
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```